# What is an application pool in IIS?

Tags: iis, iis6

I am not sure what an application pool is in IIS. I did manage to find a basic explanation, boiling down to:

"Websites can be assigned to application pools, all application pools containing specific settings for applications (allowing you to isolate websites)."

Looking at the documentation, it seems there is much more to it. I cannot find a good explanation though.

Comment: Google is your friend

Comment: @DarkcatStudios: `I cannot find a good explanation though.`

Comment: Try:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735247%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

and

https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/67e39bd8-317e-4cf6-b675-6431d4425248.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: and better:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868612/what-is-an-iis-application-pool

Comment: I felt the down-vote was just plain wrong! So I did what I could. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc, you're a nice guy. If somebody does not like a question much -- I understand that person would downvote it. I have to be honest in this case, I just can't understand how this could be considered a bad question. Thanks!

Comment: It did not make sense to me either. I prefer to leave a comment for a while before down-voting anything. It just makes sense considering that not everyone thinks the same way, has the same experience, has the same knowledge base, etc. In fact, I asked a question last night and I have to be honest- had I done a better search the first time I would have found the answer. As well, I was not paying as close attention as I could have from days of exhaustion. These things happen. Patience and understanding is a virtue. It is a good teaching moment for anyone who reads these comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications Pools are a way to segregate the worker processes that on `IIS` between web applications. They provide the ability to group common applications together so that they can share resources.

Each Application Pool has their own set of worker processes assigned to and and does not share processes with other pools.

This way, the worker processes for one application pool can not communicate directly with the worker processes of another pool (thus protecting the applications from one another). For example, putting applications for different clients into individual pools to prevent their application's processes from talking to other client's processes.

Additionally, it allows more worker processes to be allocated to pools to need them. For example, you might assign more worker processes to a customer-facing store website to handle extra load and fewer to a customer facing support site that might not need the resources for static content.